# Demystification of SQL Server optimization process

Tags: sql-server, optimization

We would like to see all variants of query plan considered during a query optimization by a SQL Server optimizer. SQL Server offers quite detailed insight using `querytraceon` options. For example `QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8615` allows us to print out MEMO structure and `QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8619` print out a list of transformation rules applied during the optimization process. That is great, however, we have several problems with trace outputs:

1. It seems that the MEMO structure contains only final variants of the query plan or variants that were later rewritten into the final one. Is there a way to find "unsuccessful/unpromising" query plans?
2. The operators in MEMO do not contain a reference to SQL parts. For example, LogOp_Get operator does not contain a reference to a specific Table.
3. The transformation rules do not contain a precise reference to MEMO operators, therefore, we can not be sure which operators were transformed by the transformation rule.

Let me show it on a more elaborated example. Let me have two artificial tables `A` and `B`:

```
WITH x AS (
        SELECT n FROM
        (
            VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
        ) v(n)
    ),
    t1 AS
    (
        SELECT ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n + 10000 * tenthousands.n + 100000 * hundredthousands.n as id  
        FROM x ones, x tens, x hundreds, x thousands, x tenthousands, x hundredthousands
    )
SELECT
    CAST(id AS INT) id, 
    CAST(id % 9173 AS int) fkb, 
    CAST(id % 911 AS int) search, 
    LEFT('Value ' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + REPLICATE('*', 1000), 1000) AS padding
INTO A
FROM t1;


WITH x AS (
        SELECT n FROM
        (
            VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
        ) v(n)
    ),
    t1 AS
    (
        SELECT ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n AS id  
        FROM x ones, x tens, x hundreds, x thousands       
    )
SELECT
    CAST(id AS INT) id,
    CAST(id % 901 AS INT) search, 
    LEFT('Value ' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + REPLICATE('*', 1000), 1000) AS padding
INTO B
FROM t1;
```

Right now, I run one simple query

```
SELECT a1.id, a1.fkb, a1.search, a1.padding
FROM A a1 JOIN A a2 ON a1.fkb = a2.id
WHERE a1.search = 497 AND a2.search = 1
OPTION(RECOMPILE, 
    MAXDOP 1,
    QUERYTRACEON 3604,
    QUERYTRACEON 8615)
```

I get quite complex output that describes MEMO structure (you may try by yourself) having 15 groups. Here is the picture, that visualizes MEMO structure using a tree.
[image]
From the tree one may observe that there were certain rules applied before the optimizer found the final query plan. For example `join commute` (`JoinCommute`), `join to hash join` (`JNtoHS`), or `Enforce sort` (`EnforceSort`). As mentioned it is possible to print out the whole set of rewriting rules applied by the optimizer using `QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 8619` options.
The problems:

1. We may find `JNtoSM` (`Join to sort merge`) rewriting rule in the 8619 list, however, the sort-merge operator is not in MEMO structure. I understand that the sort-merge was probably more costly, but why it is not in MEMO?
2. How to know whether `LogOp_Get` operator in MEMO references to table A or table B?
3. If I see rule `GetToIdxScan - Get -> IdxScan` in the 8619 list, how to map it to the MEMO operators?

There is a limited number of resources about this. I have read many of the Paul White blog posts about transformation rules and MEMO, however, the above questions remain unanswered. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Is there a way to see what were the Candidate Execution Plans generated by the Query Optimizer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265434/is-there-a-way-to-see-what-were-the-candidate-execution-plans-generated-by-the-q)

Comment: @Ronaldo thanks for the reference. So it seems that candidate plans are not accessible in SQL Server. It may be the answer to my questions ...

Comment: Just curious, what problem are you trying to solve by diving this deep into the SQL Server Engine? (I'm wondering if we can find an alternative solution to your root problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to reply to your questions:

*1. It seems that the MEMO structure contains only final variants of the query plan or variants that were later rewritten into the final one. Is there a way to find "unsuccessful/unpromising" query plans?*

No, sadly there is no way to do that. @Ronaldo pasted a nice link in the comment. My suggestion is to use the `Include Live Query Statistics`

[image]

and try to find out if you see different query plan. Use `top 10`, `top 1000`, or `*` and you will see that different query plans will be proposed. You can also use `query hint` and force your query plan to a different pattern. Basically *"do your own discarded query plan"*

*2. The operators in MEMO do not contain a reference to SQL parts. For example, LogOp_Get operator does not contain a reference to a specific Table.*

Use `QUERYTRACEON 8605`, I can see a reference to the table:

[image]

*3. The transformation rules do not contain a precise reference to MEMO operators, therefore, we can not be sure which operators were transformed by the transformation rule*

I don't see any `GetToIdxScan - Get -> IdxScan` in the query you provided. My suggestion is to use Use `QUERYTRACEON 8605`, or `QUERYTRACEON 8606`, there should be a reference there.

**EDIT:**

So *"... is it possible to see more information about the candidate plans in SQL Server."*

The reply is **no**, because there are no other candidate query plan. In fact, is a common misconception that SQL Server returns you **The Best** query plan. SQL Server simply cannot calculate for you all possible solutions: that would take... I don't know... minutes...? hours...? Calculating every single solution is unfeasible.

But if you want to investigate **why** your query plan choose that pattern you can use:

- `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` : and SQL Server will return you a tree of the logic of every single calculation of your query plan

[image]

- `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('A', 'PK_A')` : which will show you the statistics about a target table and constraint. I created a key to show you the results, naturally you will see more info if your table is queried more often

[image]

- `USE HINT('force_legacy_cardinality_estimation')` : will allow you to use the former cardinality estimation, so you can check if you query plan might have been faster with the legacy cardinality estimation .